# Justified tabs in Foundation for Apps project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, zurb-foundation

I'm looking for a way to achieve full-width/justified tabs in a container in my Foundation app. This is what's happening currently.

[image]

In Twitter Bootstrap I can [do this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified) and I'm looking for the same type of functionality in Foundation. Is it possible natively?

I'm just using the [default tabs structure example](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/tabs) right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabs in Foundation use the flexbox model. By default, their `flex-grow` is `0` (they don't grow to fill up the parent). Change it to `1` and they will. Optionally, you might want to add `text-align: center`, as now the tab text will be smaller than the tab itself:

```
div.tabs .tab-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Boom, that was easy. Guess it really had nothing to do with Foundation after all. Thanks!

Comment: All frameworks, one way or another, build the same thing: `HTML` + `CSS`.