# Foundation Tabs Expand to Fill All Available Horizontal Space in Container?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am working on rewriting parts of my existing application over to the Foundation Framework 6.  Right now I am working with Foundation Tabs, and I am trying to get the tabs to expand horizontally to fill in all available horizontal space.  This is being done to match the look and feel of the previous version of the site.

I have worked on an example in jsfiddle to find a solution.  Unfortunately it still looks like this:

[Current tab placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fYWZ.png)

Here is a link to my current progress in an example in jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9j6vpdm3/1/

This jsfiddle is an example implementation of the closest answer I was able to find in StackOverflow ([Justified tabs in Foundation for Apps project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053962/justified-tabs-in-foundation-for-apps-project)).  Unfortunately this solution did not work, as you can see the tabs are still left aligned and still have plenty of horizontal space available.

There are other solutions I have found on the Zurb forums via Google, but the answers are so old that the suggested links no longer work.

Is there a trick to getting the Foundation Tabs to dynamically expand to fill up all of the available horizontal space?

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.1.2/foundation.min.js"></script>


<style>
 div.tabs .tab-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
 </style>
 <div style="text-align: center">
   <ul class="tabs" id="example-tabs" data-tabs>
      <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-0" aria-selected="true">Title 1</a></li>
      <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-1" aria-selected="true">Title 2</a></li>
      <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-2" aria-selected="true">Title 3</a></li>
      <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel-3" aria-selected="true">Title 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-0">
        <p>Content1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-1">
        <p>Content 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-2">
        <p>Content 3 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel-3">
        <p>Content 4 </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to do this, for just about any container with direct children you are trying to control.

With a flex parent, a child can expand to fill space evenly by setting the flex property. flex: 1 0 0;

Example: https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/NJyYQE

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;

  .tabs-title {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    text-align: center;

    & + .tabs-title {
      border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@rafibomb's answer is correct and will work, but you can also leverage Foundation's built-in Utility Classes.

You can add the `flex-container` class to the `ul.tabs` element and a `flex-child-auto` class to each `li.tabs-title` element.

Here is an example:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
   <ul class="tabs flex-container" id="example-tabs" data-tabs>
      <li class="tabs-title flex-child-auto"><a href="#panel-0" aria-selected="true">Title 1</a></li>
      <li class="tabs-title flex-child-auto"><a href="#panel-1" aria-selected="true">Title 2</a></li>
      <li class="tabs-title flex-child-auto"><a href="#panel-2" aria-selected="true">Title 3</a></li>
      <li class="tabs-title flex-child-auto"><a href="#panel-3" aria-selected="true">Title 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```